# Fonts look bad in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, antialiasing

I've just downloaded and tried the font "Proxim". Then I tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari.

In Chrome, the font looks very bad. Here are some screenshots:

The first one from Chrome:

[image: Font in Chrome:]

The second one from Firefox/IE/Safari:

[image: Font in Firefox]

The code that I'm using:

```
@font-face { 
font-family: Proxima; 
src: url('proxima.otf'); 
} 

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: Proxima;
    src: url('proxima.otf') format('otf');
  }
}
html {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.25px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width: 100%;
}

.content h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: -.05em;
    font-family: Proxima,sans-serif;
    font-size:6.25em;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This is typical for Chrome. However, it looks like it will be fixed soon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018037/bad-font-rendering-chrome?rq=1

Comment: @TimMedora I found a way to fix this issue, it's by enabling DirectWrite in chrome://flags . Why won't they enable it as default  until they fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like enabling DirectWrite by default *is* the fix they are talking about. I don't know why it wasn't the default in the first place. Maybe it was slow/unstable.