# @fontface chrome rendering to high

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I have some problem with @fontface in Google Chrome. The font is rendered too high.

When I change the font to Arial, the button is allright in all browsers. When I change it to the @fontface font the text jumps up.

Below are 2 images that show the difference between Firefox and Chrome.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

What can I do?

I've tried: 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

Also I added the following for all the fonts right after the font declaration:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Museo-Sans-Rounded-100-Regular';
        src: url('../fonts/Museo-Sans-Rounded-100-Regular.svg') format('svg');
    }
}
```

Both didn't help.

What can I do? All the help is very welcome!

Comment: Hi, You may want to check out this related post on svg based fonts in chrome - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422770/font-face-svg-not-working-properly-in-chrome

Comment: Hi ViRa, thanks for the tip, going to try it out! +1 when it works ;)

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem! Thanks for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vira for pointing to the right post. The solution can be found here:

[@font-face svg not working properly in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422770/font-face-svg-not-working-properly-in-chrome)