# Is there a way I can fix webfonts in google chrome (windows)?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts

I'm using the latest chrome (47 I think) and I know there is some kind of font smoothing / anti aliasing in chrome for a couple of chrome versions now.

But my webfont looks pretty humble compared with other browsers.

Images are better than words sometimes, so look yourself

[image]

---

So my question is: Is there any way to *fix* this issue? I'm looking for a solution I can include per css/js - I don't want to tweak my browser or similar.

I use Lato as font and include it per CSS with a font size of 16px (actually 1.6rem) and a weight of 300

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700);
```

[Here a short pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeYXRW)

Comment: CSS `-webkit-font-smoothing` http://maxvoltar.com/sandbox/fontsmoothing/

Comment: @www139 changed nothing :(

Comment: Could you post your CSS?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the font or converting it to a TTF? Using the `@import` or `<link...` from Google web fonts only includes the WOFF format. IIRC they render poorly. I generally host the entire font stack locally and ensure that the CSS `font-face` declarations are ordered such that WOFF isn't the primary option, but instead a failover option.

Comment: @Quantastical I tried it hosting myself and had some really weird loading problems so I just included them per CDN because I didn't have the time to fix my server problems.

Comment: Typically, servers aren't set up by default to set the appropriate MIME type for WOFF files, which is the primary issue when hosting locally. It should be sending `application/x-font-woff` for them. I would try finding the same font as a TTF somewhere or downloading the WOFF and converting it with a tool like FontSquirrel.

Comment: @www139 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeYXRW

Comment: @Quantastical I just tried it and it changes nothing :/

Comment: Chrome is notoriously bad at font rendering on Windows, and it's pretty much out of your control. I've heard that using SVG fonts instead of TTF or WOFF can sometimes improve things, but I also believe Chrome is dropping (or has already dropped) support for SVG fonts.

Comment: Drat. I was really hoping that'd work. I remember Chrome for Windows, specifically, having rendering problems with WOFFs, and since Google fonts only uses WOFFs, that is why I had suggested it.

Comment: BTW, `16px` is not `1.6rem` unless you've explicitly set the default font size on your body to `10px`

Comment: More details at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422770/font-face-svg-not-working-properly-in-chrome); I don't think you can "fix" this problem.

Comment: @StephenThomas Yeah but I did this. I just added this note just in case, when `rem` could actually be associated with the problem.